# Javascript - Date difference is incorrect

Tags: javascript

I need to get the difference in seconds between two dates and times.

I have this script:

```
var date1 = new Date(2013,10,02,12,00,00);
var date2 = new Date(2013,10,02,12,01,00);

var diff = date2 - date1;
diff = diff / 1000;
document.write(diff);
```

Which returns the value of 60, 60 seconds difference, good.

However, when I cross over a month with 30 days, it doesn't calculate correctly.

```
var date1 = new Date(2013,9,30,12,00,00);
var date2 = new Date(2013,10,02,12,00,00);

var diff = date2 - date1;
diff = diff / 1000;
document.write(diff);
```

The result returned is 259200, which is 3 days.  The difference between September 30 and October 2 is only 2 days, 172800, because there are only 30 days in the month.  Why does Javascript seem to think there are 31 days in September?

Comment: If it's possible to use a library, you should use moment.js it's really great for these types of things: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The month numbers start with 0, not 1. So 9 is October and 10 is November.